# Cuda Fortran 4D array

Tags: arrays, cuda, fortran, pgi

My code is being slowed down by a my 4D arrays access in global memory.

I am using PGI compiler 2010.

The 4D array I am accessing is read only from the device and the size is known at run time.

I wanted to allocate to the texture memory and found that my PGI version does not support texture. As the size is known only at run time, it is not possible to use constant memory too.

Only One dimension is known at compile time like this `MyFourD(100, x,y,z)` where x,y,z are user input.

My first idea is about pointers but not familiar with pointer fortran.

If you have experience how to deal with such a situation, I will appreciate your help. Because only this makes my codes 5times slower than expected

Following is a sample code of what I am trying to do

```
int i,j,k

i = (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + threadIdx%x-1
j = (blockIdx%y-1) * blockDim%y + threadIdx%y-1

    do k = 0, 100 
        regvalue1 = somevalue1
        regvalue2 = somevalue2 
        regvalue3 =  somevalue3 

        d_value(i,j,k)=d_value(i,j,k)
     &     +myFourdArray(10,i,j,k)*regvalue1      
     &     +myFourdArray(32,i,j,k)*regvalue2      
     &     +myFourdArray(45,i,j,k)*regvalue3                    
    end do
```

Best regards,

Comment: When you say 'PGI compiler', do you mean you use OpenACC? You may want to add a tag `OpenACC` for your question.

Comment: Eric, It is not OpenACC but the mpif90

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer from @Alexander Vogt is on the right track - I would think about re-ordering the array storage.  But I would try it like this:

```
int i,j,k

i = (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + threadIdx%x-1
j = (blockIdx%y-1) * blockDim%y + threadIdx%y-1

    do k = 0, 100 
        regvalue1 = somevalue1
        regvalue2 = somevalue2 
        regvalue3 =  somevalue3 

        d_value(i,j,k)=d_value(i,j,k)
     &     +myFourdArray(i,j,k,10)*regvalue1      
     &     +myFourdArray(i,j,k,32)*regvalue2      
     &     +myFourdArray(i,j,k,45)*regvalue3                    
    end do
```

Note that the only change is to `myFourdArray`, there is no need for a change in data ordering in the `d_value` array.

The crux of this change is that we are allowing adjacent threads to access adjacent elements in `myFourdArray` and so we are allowing for coalesced access.  Your original formulation forced adjacent threads to access elements that were separated by the length of the first dimension, and so did not allow for useful coalescing.

Whether in CUDA C or CUDA Fortran, threads are grouped in X first, then Y and then Z dimensions.  So the rapidly varying *thread subscript* is X first.  Therefore, in matrix access, we want this rapidly varying subscript to show up in the index that is *also* rapidly varying.

In Fortran this index is the *first* of a multiple-subscripted array.

In C, this index is the *last* of a multiple-subscripted array.

Your original code followed this convention for `d_value` by placing the X thread index (`i`) in the first array subscript position.  But it broke this convention for `myFourdArray` by putting a constant in the first array subscript position.  Thus your access to `myFourdArray` are noticeably slower.

When there is a loop in the code, we also don't want to place the loop variable first (for Fortran, or last for C) (i.e. `k`, in this case, as Alexander Vogt did) because doing that will also break coalescing.  For *each* iteration of the loop, we have multiple threads executing in lockstep, and those threads should all access adjacent elements.  This is facilitated by having the *X thread indexed* subscript (e.g. `i`) *first* (for Fortran, or last for C).

Comment: Robert thank you.I start seeing considerable speedup. I will continue working on. It is really good to see this progress thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the indexing, i.e. let the first dimension change the Fastest. Fortran is [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)!

```
do k = 0, 100 
    regvalue1 = somevalue1
    regvalue2 = somevalue2 
    regvalue3 =  somevalue3 

    d_value(k,i,j)=d_value(k,i,j) +         &
      myFourdArray(k,i,j,10)*regvalue1 +    &
      myFourdArray(k,i,j,32)*regvalue2 +    &
      myFourdArray(k,i,j,45)*regvalue3                   
end do
```

If the last (in the original case second) dimension is always fixed (and not too large), consider individual arrays instead.

In my experience, pointers do not change much in terms of speed-up when applied to large arrays. What you could try is [strip-mining](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5262/aeugr/index.html) to optimize your loops in terms of cache access, but I do not know the compile option to enable this with the PGI compiler.

Ah, ok it is a [simple directive](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/whitepapers/pgi_accel_prog_model_1.0.pdf):

```
!$acc do vector
do k=...
enddo
```

Comment: Thank you. I will tri and let you know.

Comment: @Alexander Vogt PGI has multiple CUDA products.  PGI accelerator (for C and Fortran) accepts directive syntax.  PGI CUDA Fortran is a different product which accepts CUDA syntax in otherwise native fortran with no accelerator directives.  The posted question has CUDA syntactical elements in it (e.g. `blockIdx%x`) and so it must be CUDA Fortran (not accelerator Fortran, i.e. not using directives).

Comment: Oh, I assumed those were some custom structures... Thanks for the clarification!