# how to design grid and blocks in cuda fortran for a 3-d array

Tags: cuda, fortran

I am new to Cuda fortran. I have never worked with higher dimension grids. I just thought to start with this problem, in which i have to assign 1 thread to each cell of a 3-d array of size 46*46*19. Please can someone help me how to design the grid and blocks for this type of array and to compute the thread indices for that.

any help will be appreciated.

I have come up with this, but i don't know how to compute the thread indexes

```
    type(dim3) :: threads,blocks
    threads=dim3(16,16,4)
    blocks=dim3((xDim + threads%x - 1)/threads%x,(yDim + threads%y - 1)/threads%y,(zDim + threads%z - 1)/threads%z)
```

Comment: "Please write my code for me" is not a good SO question.  In fact, you should make an attempt at it yourself, then discuss what you've tried, and what's not working, and what you expect the results to be.  In fact, SO expects: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist "

Comment: Why can't your advisor/boss help you do this?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry about that, I won't be asking question in such stupid manner from now on, I have edited the question and added some code which shows the grids and blocks, but can u please give me a hint, how should i compute the indices of threads.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958634/cuda-fortran-4d-array/18960855#18960855)  The basic syntax to compute x,y,z indices is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown in your question is what you would use to set up the kernel launch.

Inside the kernel you could use code like this to generate thread x,y, and z indices:

```
idx = (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + threadIdx%x-1
idy = (blockIdx%y-1) * blockDim%y + threadIdx%y-1
idz = (blockIdx%z-1) * blockDim%z + threadIdx%z-1
```

This would create zero-based indexing.  You could omit the `-1` at the end of each line of code above to create one-based indexing.